googlempasのfromLatLngToPointで期待する位置が取得できない
マーカーの下ににカスタムinfoを表示したいのですがfromLatLngToPointで取得できるx,y座標が期待値と異なります。
地図のサイズ・マーカーの位置を変更してみてもだいたい同じような座標が返却されてしまいます。
fromLatLngToPoint()でdebuggerを打ちmapObjectの状態確認をしましたが下記は全て正確に取得できたので画面操作がmapObjectに反映されていないわけではなさそうです。

mapObject.getDiv()
mapObject.getCenter()
mapObject.getZoom()
mapObject.getBounds()

'use client'
import {
  AdvancedMarker,
  APIProvider,
  Map,
} from '@vis.gl/react-google-maps'
import Image from 'next/image'
import {useState } from 'react'

export const Map = () => {

  const [markers] = useState([
    {
      id: 'r4fLgXwzy2',
      name: "日本",
      position: {
        lat: 35,
        lng: 135,
      },
    },
    {
      id: 'FoHfmbTBMX',
      name: "インドネシア",
      position: {
        lat: -6.251182694680243,
        lng: 106.91072126180323,
      },
    },
  ])

  // GoogleMapオブジェクト
  const [mapObject, setMapObject] = useState<MapObject | null>(null)

  // マーカーのinfoWindow
  const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState(null)

  // 緯度経度から地図上のpx座標を算出
  const fromLatLngToPoint = (
    latLng: LatLng
  ): PositionPx | null => {
    if (!window.google || !mapObject) {
      return null
    }

    debugger
    const projection = mapObject.getProjection()
    if (!projection) {
      return null
    }

    const point = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng)
    
    if (!point) {
      return null
    }

    return {
      x: point.x,
      y: point.y,
    }
  }
  // マーカーホバー時
  const handleMouseOverMarker = (marker) => {
    setActiveMarker({
      data: marker,
      positionPx: fromLatLngToPoint(marker.position),
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      {googleMapsApiKey && mapId && (
        <APIProvider
          apiKey={googleMapsApiKey}
          language={i18n.language}
          version="quarterly"
        >
          <Map
            mapId={mapId}
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: 'calc(100vh - 145px)',
            }}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: -6.2087, lng: 106.8455 }}
            defaultZoom={13}
            fullscreenControl={false}
            mapTypeControl={false}
            // minZoom={9}
            onTilesLoaded={(mapEvent) => {
              setMapObject(mapEvent.map)
            }}
          >
            <>
              {/* marker */}
              {markers.map((marker) => (
                <AdvancedMarker
                  key={vms.id}
                  position={{
                    lat: vms.position.lat,
                    lng: vms.position.lng,
                  }}
                >
                  <Image
                    src={poi.src}
                    width={30}
                    height={40}
                    priority
                    onMouseOver={() => {
                      handleMouseOverMarker(vms)
                    }}
                    onMouseOut={() => {
                      setActiveMarker(null)
                    }}
                  />
                </AdvancedMarker>
              ))}

              {/* markerのinfoWindow */}
              {activeMarker && activeMarker.positionPx && (
                <div style={{ position: "absolute", zIndex:1000, top: positionPx.x, left: positionPx.y }}>
                  <div>
                    {positionPx.x}<br />
                    {positionPx.y}
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </>
          </Map>
        </APIProvider>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

日本を指した時

インドネシアを指した時

